# Comparing $(document.body).css() output with a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is so simple I have no idea why it's not working. I am trying to get a CSS variable value with jQuery and compare it to a string of the same value. The comparison should return `true` while it does not.

```js
var themeMode = $(document.body).css('--theme-mode');
console.log(themeMode);
console.log(themeMode == 'dark');
```

```css
:root {
  --theme-mode: dark;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: jQuery struggles reading non-standard CSS properties. Use plain JS instead

Comment: `console.log($(document.body).css('--theme-mode')` does return `dark`.

Comment: This is not a duplicate because the line above does return the string. However, it retuns false when I try to compare the strings.

Comment: because return string value is ' dark' try following code `alert(themeMode == ' dark');`

Comment: @AhmedYousif. Bravo! Thanks for your help. Shame on others who try to mark it as a duplicate without trying to understand the issue.

Comment: @sdvnksv no, it returns `undefined` as you'll see when you try this in Chrome in the edit I made to your snippet. As my first comment said, jQuery cannot reliably retrieve made-up CSS properties in a cross browser safe way. You *need* to use plain JS if you want this to work reliably.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I use jQuery 3.3.1 and it works just fine in Chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/fwt27b01/1/

Comment: Then why did you put jQuery 2.1.1 in the snippet?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, because that's the latest available in the SO editor.